# Object oriented design for iOS app with View Controllers

Tags: ios, object-oriented-analysis

I am making an iPhone app with this flow

1. On initial app launch, user sees screen asking if they want to login to social service
2. If yes, modal is launched to enter login details
3. If details submitted, modal is dismissed and a view is presented which provides interaction with the social service

My question is, in step 3, should the View Controller controlling this view be the same VC I use in step 1 or should it be a new View Controller?

I should also note that login details are saved and as long as they are, the user will never see the view in step 1 on subsequent app usage.

What is good practice in this situation?

Comment: Do it whichever way you want man.

Comment: There's no answer to "should". Its whatever makes sense. If step 1 and step 3 are both complex then two separate VCs would be best, if step 3 is very simple and straightforward then even if from a purist point of view it "ought" to be a separate VC it doesn't really matter much if its not unless somebody reviews it who's a stuck up pedantic.

Comment: 2 objectives - 1 ease of extensibility and maintainability. 2 if I apply for a job and the interviewer who reviews the code _is_ a stuck up pedant (which happens frequently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good thing you're thinking about the view controller flow at this point - you've made a good observation here:

> I should also note that login details are saved and as long as they are, the user will never see the view in step 1 on subsequent app usage.

This is a pretty clear indicator that step 1 should be a **modal view**. What that means is, it is *not* the root of your app's flow. Step 3, on the other hand, sounds like it is the root view of your app, as it is what users will encounter when they open your app afterwards. If you agree with this, then step 3 should actually be the controller presenting steps 1 and 2. And step 2 might be a push from step 1 instead of a modal view, because the user isn't going to return to step 1.

When you're in the phase of designing app flow, it's important to think about how the user will navigate between screens of your app. But, as the commenters on the question have partially observed, what *really* matters is how the information flows between screens. It's more important to have a sensible hierarchy of views than to have a sensible series of animations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, nice way to think about it. Using step 3 as the root does seem like the way to go as it works really well with the interaction design - cuts down on UI elements and interactions needed to achieve objectives, and reduces extra VC's. I can get away with 2 VC's instead of possibly 3.